# Problem while using Replace function Python

Tags: python

```
name = "RED BLUE"
rname = str(name).replace("R", "A")
rname = str(name).replace("E", "B")
rname = str(name).replace("D", "C")
rname = str(name).replace("B", "D")
rname = str(name).replace("L", "E")
rname = str(name).replace("U", "F")
rname = str(name).replace("E", "G")

print(rname)
```

It should give me an output saying:

```
ABC DEFG
```

But it didn't, I tried to search in Internet but it didn't not help so I came here.
Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are always using the **orignal** `name` - not the result `rname` that already got stuff replaced ... you overwrite `rname` all the time and only the last will "survive".

Comment: You have to use `rname` instead of `name` from second to last replace calls - or just concatening them

Comment: .. and `str(name)` is not needed - `name` IS already a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Patrick Artner you are not using `rname` but doing operations on `name`. Every time are reinitializing the `rname` variable also.

There is an elegant way to do this in python using `str.translate`

```py
name = "RED BLUE"

name = name.translate(str.maketrans({'R': 'A', 
                'E':'B', 
                'D':'C', 
                'B':'D',
                'L': 'E',
                'U': 'F',
                'E': 'G'}))
print(name)
```

```
'AGC DEFG'
```

Comment: It didn't give the output as ```'AGC DEFG'```

Comment: what output are you getting? I am getting 'AGC DEFG'

Comment: ```name = "RED BLUE"

name.translate(str.maketrans({'R': 'A', 
                'E':'B', 
                'D':'C', 
                'B':'D',
                'L': 'E',
                'U': 'F',
                'E': 'G'}))
print(name)``` I got this as output ```RED BLUE```

Comment: I see, you need to store the translated one to original variable, it is not in place operation, check the updated answer.

Comment: OK, it gave me the correct out put, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you are overwriting the variable rname. just use:

```
name = "RED BLUE"
rname = name.replace(name , "ABC DEFG")
```